# What is $errno in set_error_handler callback function?

Tags: php, error-handling

set_error_handler callback function accepts 2 mandatory arguments and 3 optional arguments.
One of which is $errno (first one).

What is its use ? Is it integer representation of E_ALL or E_NOTICE .... ?

Comment: I think that is correct looking at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).  "The first parameter, errno, contains the level of the error raised, as an integer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $errno contains the level of the error raised, as an integer.

I think this example will make it clear (not my code):

```
 switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, where did you get this code? just to check its credibility :)

Comment: Gotta love PHP.net, so should be reliable ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) regarding the *error handler*:

> The first parameter, **errno**, contains the level of the error raised, as an integer.

It will be one of the [predefined error constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), e.g. `E_USER_WARNING`, `E_NOTICE`, etc.